# Call to undefined method attach()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi am trying to use a many to many relationship but I cannot see what im doing wrong. This:

```
$meeting = new Meeting();
$meeting->attach($user);
```

causes: `BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\Meeting::attach()`

**User model**

```
  public function meetings(): BelongsToMany
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Meeting::class);
  }
```

**Meeting Model**

```
  public function users(): BelongsToMany
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }
```

**Migration**

```
    Schema::create('meeting_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('meeting_id');
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach is called in the relationship, not in the model. You should use it like this:

```
$meeting->users()->attach($user);
```

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
$meeting->users()->attach($request->user); // user may have input field name
```